# How to implement Oauth2 without sending client_secret in WSO2 APIM

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, apim

I want to get access token without submiting Base64(client_id:client_secret) in the request.

**I just want to submit  the client_id** and username and password (Password Grant Type) : **public** passoword grant type

It's called public scheme by [IBM. Please quiclky skim through this likn](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_apionprem_security_OAuth_Password_Public.html). What I like is to never send the client_secret in an access token request. The image below illustrate it (still IBM).

[image]

The problem is that WSO2 APIM requests to obtain access token **ALWAYS** include the Base64(client_id:client_secret) parameter. I would like to be able to send only the following cURL to get an access token

[image]
I would like to be able to send the following cURL to get the access token

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go to `/carbon` and list down the `Service Providers`.

2) Edit the relevant Service Provider corresponding to your `Application`.

3) Open `Inbound Configuration` > `OAuth Configuraton`.

4) Edit the OAoth app.

5) Tick `Allow authentication without the client secret`.

6) Try above curl.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Bee. It works as expected. Would it be possible to send these requests in POST insted of GET ?

Comment: Yes it is. I was confused. Thank you Bee ;-)